# How could I import a certain function in another shell script while don't execute the entire code in it?

Tags: bash, shell, import

I have two shell script, with one script need to import a function in another one, but when I use `.` to source that script, not only the function was executed, but also the other codes inside that script.

Like I have a `script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
func()
{
    echo "func was called"
}
echo "This is script.sh"
```

And a test script `test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
. ./script.sh
echo $(func)
```

When I run func.sh, the result is like this

```
This is script.sh
func was called
```

So, my question is how could I just run the `func` without the `echo` in the last line of `script.sh`

Comment: You can’t. All you can do it to make that script only contain function definitions and source it. Otherwise, next solution is to dynamically copy only functions from other script to the current script which isn’t a very clean and good idea.

Comment: No good idea: `. <(sed '$d' script.sh)`

Answer (score 0):

When you are not sure which lines you need to delete, you can try to extracht all set of lines starting with `something()` until a `}` at the first position of the line. This might fail (now or in the future), you can consider extracting the functions.

util.sh (first line is a trick avoiding calling it without sourcing)

```
#!/bin/echo "This file should be sourced."
func()
{
    echo "func was called"
}
```

Modified script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
. ./util.sh
echo "This is script.sh"
```

And test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
. ./util.sh
# echo not needed in "echo $(func)"
func
```